# I can't get replace / replaceAll to work

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I need to show data from database that supposed to be shown:

```
in the html: Beh&#228;lter
in the browser: Behälter
```

but instead, I got data like this:

```
in the html: Beh&amp;#228;lter
in the browser: Beh&#228;lter
```

So I need to change the `&amp;` back to `&`. I use replaceAll and replace method from the Java's String class. But it didn't work. I even check whether the String has & or not using indexOf method, but it didn't even seems to catch or even see the `&amp;` sign.

My code:

```
// supposed the value returned by the getObject function is "Beh&amp;#228;lter"
String text = (String)getObject("value");

if (text.indexOf("&amp;") >= 0) text = "abc" + text;

text = text.replace("&amp;", "&");
text = text.replaceAll("&amp;", "&");

if (text.indexOf("&amp;") >= 0) text = text + "def";
text = text + "xyz";
```

The result is

```
in the html: Beh&amp;#228;lterxyz
in the browser: Beh&#228;lterxyz
```

Is there anything wrong with how I type and use replace / replaceAll? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yes. I suppose that if the ampersand is replaced, the browser will automatically display the &#228 character in its unicode character counterpart. But when I look on the page source, the &#228 character is still written as `&amp;#228;`, not `&#228;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) for the StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml().

Feed it your string with the encoded characters, and it should spit it out decoded.

Comment: At first, I don't want to use this kind of solution that depends on external library, because my development environment is kinda different. So I don't know whether I can import any external libraries like usual. But then I give it a shot, and not only I can import and use the library, it even works great! Thanks!